# ASP.NET MVC Send List from View to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

I'm trying to create a product model with ID,Name and a list of specifications like above:

My model:

```
  public class Product 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Spec> Specifications { get; set; }
}

 public class Spec
{
    public int SpecID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product,List<Spec> Specifications)
    {
     ......
    }
```

My View:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-2"><h3>Specifications</h3></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <table id="tblSkills" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
                            <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="Name1" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="Description" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Add" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="SaveAll" class="bntbtn-block btn-success" />

                <br />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

so it should looks like this:

[image: Create View]

I also added some Scripts so that I can enter or remove specifications, the information will be displayed inside a `tbody` tag in a table.

[image: Added more Specification]

The problem is that I don't really know how to pass my list of specifications to my controller, or should I try another way of input multiple specifications instead of using table. I'm looking for a way to input it using `HTMLHelper` like the one I did with Product's Name.

I apologize if my question is unclear. If you have any question to understand more, feel free to ask me. Thanks for any advise or solution.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the model to a view from controller you need to:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<Spec> Specifications)
{
     return View(Specifications);
}
```

and in your view add these to on top of the view:

```
 @using PathOfYourSpecificationsModel
 @model List<Spec>

 using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-2"><h3>Specifications</h3></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <table id="tblSkills" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
                            <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="Name1" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="Description" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Add" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="SaveAll" class="bntbtn-block btn-success" />

                <br />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

After user clicks add button you need another [HttpPost] method for Create. Which should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<Spec> Specifications)
    {
     // Specifications should be filled with view values.
    // Do your logic here. Ex: Save the data to database
    }
```

Comment: I mean I need to pass a list from my VIEW to CONTROLLER after I have entered  information to create a product. And so on my controller is already added with [HttpPost] method.

Comment: As I mentioned above in the HttpPost method List<Spec> Specifications is your list from view.

Comment: The controller can't receive any list since there is not any list named "specifications" in view. How can i get the data from table and put it inside a list so that system can recognize with HtmlHelper

Answer (score 0):

For adding dynamic control fields, it is advised to use helper methods.

The AddNewRow helper method will return the html elements can one can make changes like changing the html attributes.

the html attributes should be unique and it is advised to use increment value for each element.

the attributes of html elements returned from helper method are changed in addNewRow() of javascript function.

Detailed steps are provided below.

**In Product Model**

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Spec> Specifications { get; set; }
    }

    public class Spec
    {
        public int SpecID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult AddProduct()
        {

            Product product = new Product();

            product.Specifications = new List<Spec>()
            {
                new Spec()
            };
            return View(product);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            return View(product);
        }
    }
```

**In AddProduct.cshtml**

```
@model Product
@using WebApplication3.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddProduct";
}


@helper AddNewRow()
{

    <tr id="trRow_0">
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Specifications[0].IsRemoved, new { id = "hdnSpecIsRemoved_0" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Specifications[0].Name, new { id = "txtSpecName_0" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Specifications[0].Description, new { id = "txtSpecDesc_0" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeRow(0)">Remove Row</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

}

<h2>AddProduct</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{


    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

    </div>


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Specifications[0].Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Specifications[0].Description)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tBody">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Specifications.Count; i++)
            {
                string trRow = "trRow_" + i;
                <tr id="@trRow">
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Specifications[i].IsRemoved, new { id = "hdnSpecIsRemoved_" + i })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Specifications[i].Name, new { id = "txtSpecName_" + i })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Specifications[i].Description, new { id = "txtSpecDesc_" + i })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeRow(@i)">Remove Row</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" onclick="addNewRow()">Add New Row</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <br />
    <button type="submit">Save All</button>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNewRow() {
        var totalSpecCount = $('#tBody tr').length;

        var newRowData = `@(AddNewRow())`;
        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("Specifications[0]", "Specifications[" + totalSpecCount + "]")
        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("txtSpecName_0", "txtSpecName_" + totalSpecCount);
        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("txtSpecDesc_0", "txtSpecDesc_" + totalSpecCount);
        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("trRow_0", "trRow_" + totalSpecCount);

        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("removeRow(0)", "removeRow(" + totalSpecCount+")");
        newRowData = newRowData.replaceAll("hdnSpecIsRemoved_0", "hdnSpecIsRemoved_" + totalSpecCount);


        $('#tBody').append(newRowData);
    }


    function removeRow(recordId) {
        var trId = "#trRow_" + recordId;

        var hdnSpec = "#hdnSpecIsRemoved_" + recordId;
        $(hdnSpec).val(true);

        $(trId).hide();
    }


</script>
```

Here, the method addNewRow will call the helper methods and change the html attributes of the element based on row count.

In strongly typed view, the index values should unique for the list so that it can be posted using model binding

**Final Result**

[image: Add Product Page]

[image: Product specification data in controller]

Note: In remove row method we have to hide the element instead of removing the element completely. This is used to achieve post the list directly. To know what the rows that are removed a flag called IsRemoved is to true.

If we remove the element, the index value will not be in sequence and one cannot post the form.